# How can I return an empty instance from a getter in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I have a store that by default returns `undefined` for a particular attribute:

```
// store.js

export const state = {
    locationLoading: false,
    locationsLoading: false,
    locations: [],
    location: undefined, <--
};
```

In my component, I am using a getter within the computed attribute:

```
// component.vue

...
computed: {
    location() {
      return this.$store.getters['location/location']; // returns undefined or a location
    },
  },

...
```

Within my data for a location I have an array:

```
// location.json

...
"name": "my location",
"messaging": [
    {
        "email": {
            "fromName": "No Reply <noreply@example.com>",
            "fromAddress": "noreply@example.com"
            }
     }
],
```

If I am visiting a url such as `/locations/123` everything works great. There are no errors; the page renders correctly including validation.

If  visit `/locations` for example,  get a list of *all* locations.

The issue I am having is using [vuelidate](https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-collections-validation) for my validation. Because in my `/locations` route, there isn't a location to load, my getter returns `undefined` (as expected).

The error I am getting is

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')"

Which makes sense since my `location` is undefined.

Here is what I am using to validate `messaging`:

```
// component.vue

<input type="text" v-model.trim=" $v.location.messaging.$each.$iter[0].email.fromAddress.$model"
/>
```

I could pass a location in as a `prop` that contained every attribute. For example:

```
// component.vue

props: {
   location: {
       type: Object,
       required:false,
       default:() => ({
         name: '',
         messaging: [{
           email: {
             fromName: '',
             fromAddress: '',
           },
         }],
       ...
```

Doing this clears all errors, but I feel that is pretty fragile. If I decide to add a new attribute to a location, I need to remember to add it here too.

How can I return an empty object that satisfies validation?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) :

```
<input type="text" 
  v-model.trim="
  $v.location?.messaging?.$each.$iter[0].email.fromAddress.$model"
/>
```

Comment: Hi Nikola - thank you for your suggestion! I explored that direction and found that it seems optional chaining isn't supported in vue 2 templates. Perhaps there is a work-around that is available that I need to look at further. For now, I may need to just pass an empty object as a prop to my form.